# Inline styles are not working in outlook from share point online copy and paste?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint, outlook

We are using  in share point site. Inline styles are not working when we copy and paste from share point online to windows outlook app.

Some ideas got from stack overflow, append inside span tag like this,

```
<span>
  <a href="www.google.com">text</a>
<span>
```

when we give like this, then inline styles are working fine(color changed) but after copy and paste in outlook,  click event is not working in outlook.

Note: Normally copy and paste click event is working in outlook

Thanks in advance